# Laravel project is showing the contents of the public folder when accessed through your VHost

Tags: laravel, macos, apache, vhosts

I've made the vhost to show laravel project in it. But instead its showing me the list of content of laravel project, not running it.
For testing I generated a new laravel project and in that even i could see the file listing of public directory.
Here's my vhost code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin wosomtest.com
ServerName wosomtest.com
ServerAlias wosomtest.com
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www/wosom/public"
<Directory "/usr/local/var/www/wosom/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apps/apache/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apps/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Code inside .htaccess of public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Getting no error inside the storage/logs.
Here's what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [the default Laravel `.htaccess`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/public/.htaccess)?  What have you tried?  Is PHP working, eg does a `phpinfo();` page work?  Have you specified a `DirectoryIndex`?  There are *many* other similar questions here with many answers, have you been through those?  Eg searching for "*Apache shows list not PHP*" will give you plenty of things to check.

Comment: Yes, for testing i generated a new laravel project but its also showing me the same. I'm sure, there's some configuration missing. Other .htaccess was being used of default laravel.

Comment: Missing rewrite php module most likely, also try to see if you have any other site enabled like 000-default.conf and so forth

Comment: @Lk77 Yes, i have 2 other projects but they're not in laravel and they're working in vhost. Laravel new project is even showing this files content to me.

Comment: If you click on index.php, do you see your laravel application ?